# NodeJS and MYSQL - ER_ACCES_DENIED_ERROR: Acces denied for ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I am learning Node JS and I am trying to connect it with my sql, but I have the following error when I try to run node.

```
C:\Users\daniel.gutierrez\Desktop\Portal>node index.js
odizimcomisrunning  localhost: 3000
C:\Users\daniel.gutierrez\Desktop\Portal\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.
s:80
       throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
       ^

Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using pass
ord: NO)
   at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\daniel.gutierrez\Desktop\Port
al\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
   at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\daniel.gutierrez\Desktop\Portal\node_modu
les\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:124:18)
   at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\daniel.gutierrez\Desktop\Portal\node_modu
les\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:278:23)
   at Parser.write (C:\Users\daniel.gutierrez\Desktop\Portal\node_modules\mysql
\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
   at Protocol.write (C:\Users\daniel.gutierrez\Desktop\Portal\node_modules\mys
ql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
   at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\daniel.gutierrez\Desktop\Portal\node_modules
\mysql\lib\Connection.js:91:28)
   at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\daniel.gutierrez\Desktop\Portal\node_modules
\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10)
   at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
   at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
   at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
   --------------------
   at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\daniel.gutierrez\Desktop\Portal\node_modules\
mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
   at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\daniel.gutierrez\Desktop\Portal\node_modules
\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
   at Connection.connect (C:\Users\daniel.gutierrez\Desktop\Portal\node_modules
\mysql\lib\Connection.js:118:18)
   at Connection._implyConnect (C:\Users\daniel.gutierrez\Desktop\Portal\node_m
odules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:453:10)
   at Connection.query (C:\Users\daniel.gutierrez\Desktop\Portal\node_modules\m
ysql\lib\Connection.js:198:8)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\daniel.gutierrez\Desktop\Portal\public\confi
g\passport.js:10:16)
   at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

this looks like my user declare isn't taken in the variable. this is my connection module.

```
// node-mysql
var mysql = require('mysql');

// Conexion a exportar
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'db_test',
});

// Evento en case de error
connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err.code);
});

// Exportar la variable como modulo
module.exports.connection = connection;
```

Can help me with this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure you have entered correct username

Comment: yes, I did.... and I had created a new user in MySQL server with the same privileges than 'root' but I have the same error using it.

Answer (score 0):

So as a test I might suggest changing the "on-connection" part to this:

```
connection.connect((err) => {
if (err) throw err;
console.log("Connected!");
});
```

This is just a check to see if your program can connect to the DB
//
Adicionalmente, puedes quitar el "port: 3306" en tu declaración de connection ya que este puerto es el normal de MySQL